# WSO2 API Manager - Is there any custom way which can verify input parameter for API?

Tags: wso2

We hava an API which has 2 optional parameters, now we expect wso2am to verify these 2 parameters for the API, like their format and value and even make one of them as mandatory to API, for example.
Is there any custom way we can do this? like implement a interface by encapsulating validation logic inside and then modify some configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can write your mediation and plug into the sequence, by that you easily inject your custom code. I think this will help you.
http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/AM140/Adding+a+Mediation+Extension

Comment: Thanks, I think it could solve my problem, it seems I need to create a new custom class (may be extends APIAuthenticationHandler), and then register it into configuration file.

Comment: Can you provide a example for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can define the logic as a custom sequence extension

OR

If you check APIManager synapse config/api folder, server will create api configurations for each and every APIs which you publish. You can edit that manually with the [validate](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB470/Validate+Mediator) mediator to validate your requests. Validate mediator requires schema, so you can define your schema fro your request formats.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but where is UI configuration for validate mediator in API Manager? and could you provide a sample for that?

Comment: UI we are not shipping with APIManager. For that you can use DevStudio. And for validate mediator sample you can check wso2esb documentation

Comment: Yes, now I developed a custom mediator in DevDtudio(just print request body), 
and then export mediator project to a JAR and put it in /WSO2AM_HOME/repository/components/lib. 
finally I modify my api configuration xml as below: 

<resource methods="GET" url-mapping="/*">
  <inSequence>
     <class name="org.wso2.sample.CustomMediator"/>
      <property name="POST_TO_URI" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
         ....
  </inSequence>
  
But it didn't work, I don't know which steps I did wrong?